# Appending a Hex Value to a String

Tags: java, android, append, hex

I have a little problem in Java/Android when appending Hex / Integer values to a String.

```
String s="D###" + Character.toString((char)(int)185);
```

HEX equivalent of INTEGER 185 is B9. When I convert/transmit the values in the string s to HEX, I have the following

```
44 23 23 23 C2 B9
```

Instead of **44 23 23 23 B9**. I have no idea from where this **C2** came from. All I want is the actual 8 Bit byte/character value in the string.

Please do help me solve the issue

Comment: Integer.toHexString(int i)  outputs **44 23 23 23 62 39** in which 62 39 is the HEX equivalent of B9  62(B) 39(9)

Comment: ` StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.append("D###");
 sb.append(Integer.toHexString(185));`

B9 is the HEX EQUIVALENT OF 185, However, it considers B & 9 as Characters for which the HEX values are 62 and 39

Comment: Integer.toHexString(185) returns B9 as string. I want the charater equivalent of 185 to be appended to the string.

Comment: if so, use `String(int[] codePoints, int offset, int count)` or `Character.toChars(int codePoint)`

Comment: none of the method works. The moment I append it to the string it becomes **C2 B9** and occupies 2 bytes.  Someone pls advice.

Comment: @ArunR Can you show the code where you transmit/convert the given string to HEX string?

Comment: My goal is to send a string along with Integer values to a specific IP address.  The integer value will be between 0-255 and it has to be converted into a byte before appending it to the string.

**integer level=185;
String ss="D###" + Character.toString((char)(int)level);**

Everything works fine, the problem is 185 doesn't get converted into B9 (when the packets are viewd in HEX). 0x44 0x23 0x23 0x23 0xC2 0xB9. I have no idea from where 0xC2 is coming from. The total length of the packet is also higher by 1 byte.

Comment: see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b9/index.htm and search for `C2`

Comment: UTF-8 (hex) 0xC2 0xB9 (c2b9). This is what I get. Is there a way to pull out only B9 which is the HEX equivalent for 185???

Comment: yes: send array of bytes, not a String

Comment: How did you convert the string? When I just print characters as hex, I don't see any C2.